Removing dictionary from dictionary list
I'm writing a script using Meraki's Python Library that uses a for loop to grab a dictionary list of firewall rules which is written to a variable.
From there I'm inserting a dictionary into line 0.
The issue is that there's a dictionary in the list I need to remove. The key number of the rule changes per network because some of them already have rules, but it's always the last item in the list and contains the same info.
It's formatted as the following -
{'rules': [
{'comment': 'XXX', 'policy': 'deny', 'srcCidr': 'IP', 'destCidr': 'IP'},
 {'comment': 'Remove', 'policy': 'allow', 'srcCidr': 'IP', 'destCidr': 'IP'}
]}

In this example, the second line would need removing, but further down the if loop, the one that would need to be removed may be the 4th item due to other entries preceding it.
I've looked at creating an if statement for it but I have no idea how I would format it.

Break down what you need:

what do you need to modify?
exactly how do you need to modify it?

The data you have is a dictionary (say d), and you know that the part of the dictionary you need to modify is a list, which is the value for key 'rules'. You can access that list with d['rules']. And you can access elements of that list with d['rules'][index].
The list contains dictionaries, but all you need to is remove the last one in the list, so it doesn't really matter what type of object you're removing. You can access the last element in a list, by counting from the rear d['rules'][-1]. Note that Python starts from 0 at the start, but has to start from -1 at the rear (since there's no difference between 0 and -0).
And to remove/unset a variable in Python, you can use del, which also works for removing dictionary entries:
del d['rules'][-1]


If the dictionary is always on last position, you can use pop function:
# I am assuming you have a dict response
response = {'rules': [
 {'comment': 'XXX', 'policy': 'deny', 'srcCidr': 'IP', 'destCidr': 'IP'},
 {'comment': 'Remove', 'policy': 'allow', 'srcCidr': 'IP', 'destCidr': 'IP'}
]}

# removes the last item in a list
response['rules'].pop()

print(response)

If that can be in any position or if you can have multiple dictionaries to delete, maybe you can use a comprehension or filter function to filter the desired dictionaries:
response = {'rules': [
 {'comment': 'XXX', 'policy': 'deny', 'srcCidr': 'IP', 'destCidr': 'IP'},
 {'comment': 'Remove', 'policy': 'allow', 'srcCidr': 'IP', 'destCidr': 'IP'}
]}

key = 'comment'
value = 'Remove'

# Option1 - comprehension
rules = [d for d in response['rules'] if d[key] != value]

# Option2 - filter
rules = list(filter(lambda d: d.get(key) != value, response['rules']))

response['rules'] = rules

print(response)


Thank you, this was very informative. The pop function should work for what I'm trying to do, and the other options will work great if for some reason my script fails and I have to remove duplicates of what the original script entered
